# Multiple ajax request at a time Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

Can anybody help me about this . I want to load multiple xml url's from a single store .i can     do it if i use different stores for each request but it will make my code heaviear .can any body help me /
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could send several Ext.Ajax.request() and just append the resulting data to your targeted store (usually configured with memory proxy).

Comment: you didn't understand what i mean to say  i wanna hit multiple urls at a time and getting the xml in response ?